# ENS Registrar Initializing ...

Tags: ether, metamask, console, ens, name-registrar

I am trying to bid on a domain. However it says "Initializing ENS Registrar" ...

[image]

So ... I check the JavaScript Console (as recommended) and here is what it says:

[image]

However I don't know what to do now...

Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, those red error messages are unrelated. Those are fonts that have failed to load.

The ENS registrar dapp has had some bad performance with MetaMask, but MetaMask is pushing a patch to help mitigate the issue later today, so I would recommend trying this again soon.

Another way to try sooner:
 - Change your MetaMask network to another and back again (the top left menu in MetaMask).
 - Then reload the page.